# Faster Screen Capture

Tags: performance, screenshot, shutter

Good day everyone,

I use screen capture utilities to create Anki study flash cards. I have been using the **Shutter** application with the "Selection" option which allows me to drag the capture region and save it to the clipboard.

Unfortunately it is slow.After hitting the the capture hotkey or selection the option here is a delay for 1 - 2 seconds.  I have edited the preferences to ensure there is no delay set.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening / and or recommend another fast screen capture utility that allows me to choose a capture selection and have it sent to the clipboard?

Currently using Ubuntu 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fast screenshot you could use the command-line program `scrot`. Using it is simple:
`scrot filename.png -s`
with the -s option allowing to grab a selection of the screen.

Unfortunately, I don't know how you can redirect output to the clipboard.

Another option is the use of `xwd`. However, this one does not allow interactive selection of the region to take a picture of.

EDIT: I always forget about this easier way. If you have Gimp installed, it is very easy to grab a screenshot by using `File>Create>Screenshot`. It is very fast and you can edit your screenshot right away or copy to clipboard.

Comment: Thanks,Unfortunately this does seem to be the fastest way. I am not sure why shutter's response is so much slower than Greenshot on windows. Not the end of the world though. Thanks guys for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINT</kbd>, select what you want to capture and click on `copy to clipboard`